# Excel replace multiple text options within one cell with other text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

How can I replace one set of text options with another? I was thinking that an Index/Match combination might work, but I cant figure it out. Perhaps a VLookup function?

For example:

My report output looks like this.

```
Not Applicable (appointment offered)

No Contact

Not Applicable (appointment offered)

Not Applicable (appointment offered)
```

And I need to create a column next to it that matches the following:

```
01 = No Contact

02 = Declined Services

03 = Currently Enrolled

04 = Not Applicable (appointment offered)

05 = Other"
```

Here is a different example.

Report Output looks like this:

```
Clinic-South

Clinic-3rd St

Clinic-Columbus
```

And I need to replace with the following:

```
3rd St.-->  076465

South-->    613797

9th St.-->  878652
```

Columbus location should return as an error.

Answer (score 0):

For the **First example** write an array:

```
Column1          Column2  
No Contact          01   
Declined Services   02
```

Make sure you format the column as text in order to write 01, 02... and in the new column where you have your Data write the following:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$I$1:$J$5,2,FALSE)
```

Where:

- $I$1:$J$5 are the references of the above array (absolute references to let you drag the formula)
- A1 is your first Data
- 2 is the value in the second column to return 01, 02....
- False to check for exact match

And you can drag the formula down.

For the **Second Example**

If your Data is always like the example, Write the following formula

```
=IF(RIGHT(A17,7)="3rd St.",SUBSTITUTE(A17,"3rd St.","076465"),IF(RIGHT(A17,7)="9th St.",SUBSTITUTE(A17,"9th St.","878652"),IF(RIGHT(A17,5)="South",SUBSTITUTE(A17,"South","613797"),IF(RIGHT(A17,8)="Columbus","Error",A17))))
```

A17 is your Data reference and the formula checks for the right characters to substitute it with numbers